# best way to communicate short messages over wifi with hardware device

Tags: iphone, sockets, tcp, communication, wifi

I would like to communicate with a wifi device via an ad-hoc network. The messages received by the iPhone are quite short and the responses also (not more than about 100 bytes). The way it works is that the iPhone app waits to receive messages from the device and then responds with an answer.

SInce I am new to networking I really do not know where to start best. I looked into CFNetwork, asyncsocket project and other links on the net but did not find one single example which I can use as a starting point.

What is the best way to program this kind of wifi communication. I would really love to find a working set of mac and iPhone apps that I could use as a starting point. Later I have to port it to PC using VB.Net. But I could also start with iPhone <-> PC.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Per the accepted answer, this is a duplicate: [Most effective way to do networking on Mac/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269613/most-effective-way-to-do-networking-on-mac-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an identical question with a full answer:

[Most effective way to do networking on Mac/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269613/most-effective-way-to-do-networking-on-mac-iphone/4271926#4271926)

Comment: Thanks very much, this confirms that Asyncsocket is the way to go in my case too. Now I really need some help to get started. How do I best test if my app works with a Mac? Do I need two separate apps - one on the iPhone the other running on the Mac? Isn't there some working sample available for beginners? Could you please direct ,, Thanks very much°