# GKSession sendDataToAllPeers on client?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, gamekit

My current sessionMode is GKSessionModeServer. If I'm on a client and I do the following:

```
[mySession sendDataToAllPeers:packet withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

Will that send data to every peer in the server or just to the server itself. Sorry for asking a simple question, but I only have 2 devices to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

**Yes, it will send the data to ALL the thingies connected to that server**.

BTW if you're just getting started with networking, you may find this useful...

[Most effective way to do networking on Mac/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269613/most-effective-way-to-do-networking-on-mac-iphone/4271926#4271926)

And here is an **absolutely critical tip** regarding gamekit:

Critical tip: [Client/Server GKSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194394/client-server-gksessions/4194685#4194685)

You have done the right thing by using GKSessionModeServer.