# Iphone Found Bonjour Service in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, bonjour

I have a simple question: is a good practice to find a connect Bonjour Services in the app Delegate and comunicate with them through app delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Make yourself some nice classes to do it in.

By the way, here is some secret knowledge that may help if you are starting with gamekit !

[Client/Server GKSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194394)