# Simultaneous Bluetooth Connections on Android or iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, networking, mobile, bluetooth

Although I feel like this question has been beat to death. I still haven't found a definitive answer. But now, I'm going to try and make things a LITTLE more specific, maybe some of you bluetooth gurus can put it in terms I can understand!

Is it possible to have simultaneous bluetooth connections? For example, phone A sends data to phone B, then B sends that data to phone C, who then sends it back to phone A.

If this is possible, the phones would need to have multiple (at least 2) bluetooth sockets open at one time.

If this is not possible, do you know if it would be possible close a socket, and open another quickly enough to simulate this functionality? (given that the phones are already paired)

Let me know what you think!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iPhone, you can use GameKit's peer to peer mode for this.. it's a bit confusing but it works:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1

[Client/Server GKSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194394/client-server-gksessions)

But note that it is not (or nearly not) possible to connect iOS with Android via bluetooth (unless you create an app for jailbroken devices)

Comment: Hmmm I see.  That makes sense. I wonder if there's similar functionality for Android. 

BTW, you mentioned that it was "nearly not possible" to connect iOS and Android. What makes you add that "nearly" bit?

Comment: You could reverse engineer apple's bluetooth specs and create low-level bluetooth libs for Android..