# Server-Client based just on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to communicate among iOS devices via wifi using socket. There is an iOS devices play server role (open listening socket to wait for another). Other devices will be clients and use their socket connect to the server iOS device.I am not allow to communicate via any web server, just among these iOS devices.

Is there any simple solutions for this, may be tell me briefly what I can use. if just using Objective C, it will be better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search for Bonjour, NSNetService and NSNetServiceBrowser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've search for Bonjour, it's somethings what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: welcome. Please accept the answer if you think it is your answer

Comment: Do you know if any of those Services work with 3G internet connection as well? So if I have the IP of the device connected to the mobile internet am I able to speak with it like if it was on Wi-Fi? (I know, that IP is not static and it is recommended to use a DNS server which gives me the current IP, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use the GameKit Framwork.

There is a similar question:
[Client/Server GKSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194394/client-server-gksessions)

You can also check out the official Doc:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank for your answer, TedCheng. I tried GameKit Framework, but I want to use socket because through socket, I can communicate between iOS device with may be an Android device or another platform. Do I think right? GameKit framework just allow 2 iOS devices.

Comment: I have searched "ios and android peer to peer connection" on google. Seems there have been some existing discussion about that.
Maybe you can have a look

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestion. Maybe I will take a look at this. :) But if you have any suggestion for my original question, please tell me.